# Create a range slider in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have tried a lot of npm packages but it seems that none of them are compatible with Expo.

I am thinking of building a range slider by myself, but as far as I know, there is no range input component in react native.

What I need is something like this :

https://www.bypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/css-js-range-slider.png

How can I achieve this ?

I am using expo version 5.4.12.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using a slider package (like [react-native-multi-slider](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider)) and measure the location of the marker using [React Native's measure](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation.html#measurecallback). Combining these two tools you can create an element to be positioned above the marker every time the user interact with slider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried it and it does not work with expo

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://medium.com/range-slider-for-react-native-expo-compatible/range-slider-for-react-native-expo-compatible-b9af03fce353)

Here is an example of making custom range slider which is compatible with expo sdk